# Remote Service - Android

Tags: android, service, aidl

I have been working with the AIDL as a form of invoke methods from a device to another device (Android Devices), but this is not working in that way, however works in a unique device, only to local level, so i want to make it but of remote form, specifically making calls of methods from device to another devices, as i said in the firsts lines. That is possible? how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is currently not possible to target a service running on a separate device with an AIDL binding. There are many many alternative RPC implementations you can use, but that one currently does not support targeting a service ona remote device.

It may be possible to overload the implementation but definitely not on a standard device.

Comment: Ohh man....this is a bad news because i had the hope in AIDL for get my objetive, but anyway thanks so much !!